# how to display popup on the click of submit buttonof a form?

Tags: angularjs, popup

I have a form and two text field in it , on the click of submit button of form I want to generate the pop up and display values inserted in the text field of form.???

Comment: How do you submit the form? What does your form look like? A button with ng-click should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-model. Here is an example:

-HTML

```
<div>
     <input type="text" ng-model="input1"/>
     <input type="text" ng-model="input2" />
     <button ng-click="submitText()">Submit</button>
  </div>
```

-Controller:

```
$scope.submitText= function(){
      var text1 = $scope.input1;
      var text2 = $scope.input2;
      alert(text1+' '+text2);
        };
```